# Swift, phone number regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift

Hopefully a simple one,

I need a a limit of 8 numbers, the user need to write 8 number no more or less.

For now this is my code:

```
telefonRegex = "^(?=.*[0-9])$"
```

But it is not working, I just heard about regex fyi.

Comment: `telefonRegex = "^[0-9]{8}$"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your current regex never matches a string because it requires to start matching at the start of the string (`^`), then makes a forward check to require a digit (`[0-9]`) to appear after any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) and then tries to match the end of the string right after the beginning - tha is, it matches an empty string but also requires at least 1 digit in it.

You may just use

```
let telefonRegex = "^[0-9]{8}$"
```

or

```
let telefonRegex = "\\A[0-9]{8}\\z"
```

to match a string that only consists of 8 digits.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (may be replaced by `\\A` in the string literal)
- `[0-9]{8}` - exactly 8 occurrences of any digit
- `$` - end of string (to make sure the very end of string is matched, use `\\z` in the string literal).